# pgp decryption using camel gave out of memory Error

Tags: apache-camel

I am seeking if you can help in with the below error that is been thrown. I have tried to increase the heap size  but it is still complaining about the same.

The process file endpoint doing the decryption of 3GB file size and more.., and it complaints about it, but with other files, it worked fine.
I am wondering why the the, in case of the heap issue, I am seeing null, , i.e

I have tried to gave the heap size upto 8GB still process complaint about it. I guess it may not be related to the JVM heap, I may request your input what would be the possible cause of it and any remediation can be done on.

> [//some/folder/Receive] FileConsumer                   WARN  Consumer
> Consumer[file:///some folder/Receive?delete=true] failed polling
> endpoint: Endpoint[file:///somefolder/Receive?delete=true]. Will try
> again at next poll. Caused by: **[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - null]**
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
> at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
> at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
> at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
> at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
> at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.unmarshal(PGPKeyAccessDataFormat.java:401)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:67)
> at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:111)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:82)
> at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
> at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:423)
> at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)
> at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Try enable stream caching: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/stream-caching.html

Comment: And what version of Camel are you using